# Python: How to use re by defining an exception?

Tags: python, regex

This is a very newbie's question. I tried a lot on my own, but without success.

I want to use `re` to find numbers from a string, but with exception of the minus symbol:

```
>>> a1 = "25 mm"
>>> b1 = "-25 mm"
>>> c1 = "s-25"
>>> d1 = "s25-"
```

`a = re.sub(r'\D', "", a1)` gives `"25"`, which is fine.

I would like to ask, how to use `re` for **b1** and **c1** to get `"-25"`, and how to for **d1** to get `"25"`, because the minus symbol is behind the nummber.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try this one : `re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you can try this one :

```
import re
s = re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?")
a1 = "25 mm"
b1 = "-25 mm"
c1 = "s-25"
d1 = "s25-"
print(s.search(d1).group(0))
print(s.search(b1).group(0))
print(s.search(c1).group(0))
print(s.search(a1).group(0))
```

it gives the o/p like this :

```
25 #d1
-25 #b1
-25 #c1
25 #a1
```

Comment: Great! Thanks very much!

Comment: @LucasMeier glad to help you :)